# How to get element stay on top of the browers in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari

I am trying to make `div` stay on top of the browser after user scroll down to certain position

I have something like

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 301) {
           $('#div').css('top', $(window).scrollTop()-277);
       }else if($(window).scrollTop() < 301){
         $('#div').css('top', 0);
       }
    });
```

It works great in desktop browser. However, it is a bit bugged in iPad safari. The `$('#div')` will '`jump`' to the top 'After' the position is > `301` instead of stay on top all the time. Basically, it's like the browser ignore the codes when user is actually scrolling but when user stop scrolling, the `$('#div')` jumps to the top. I was hoping someone here can help me to solve this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried css:

```
#div { 
  top: 0;
  position: fixed; 
}
```

Comment: I can't because I don't want to make it stay on top all the time when the page first loaded

Comment: affix.js (from the bootstrap css makers) seems to do what you want: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following class in your CSS:

```
#div {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
}
#div.is-fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

and then in your JS code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 301) {
       $('#div').addClass("is-fixed");
   } else {
     $('#div').removeClass("is-fixed");
   }
});
```

This would simplify your code greatly and improve performance.

However I believe your issue is that on iOS devices the scroll event is fired when the user finished scrolling with the finger. You'll probably have to deal with touch events to have your scroll perfect.